# SQL optional join and default value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Schema:

```
TABLE entry
(
  entry_id serial NOT NULL,
  section_id integer,
  deleted integer DEFAULT 0,
  grp_id integer,
  data json,
  last_edited bigint,
  last_editor_id integer
)
```

The column `e.data` might look like this: `{f22: 5, f251: 0}` or `{f22: -1, f251: 0}` if f22 is 'not set' or `{f251: 0}` in which case I'd like it to default to -1.

I'd like to sort by the "parent"'s name (f27), but if a parent is not linked I'd like to put it at the bottom of the sort. How can I accomplish this?

Currently it only returns rows where the join matches (it shouldn't match if f22 isn't set or is -1).

```
        SELECT e.*
        FROM entry AS e
        JOIN entry as parent ON parent.entry_id = cast(e.data->>'f22' as integer)
        WHERE e.deleted = 0 AND e.section_id = $1 AND e.grp_id = $2 
        ORDER BY parent.data->>'f27' ASC
```

What I ended up with:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM entry AS e
LEFT JOIN entry as parent ON (
    parent.entry_id = cast(e.data->>'f22' as integer)
    AND parent.deleted = 0
    AND parent.grp_id = $2
)
WHERE e.deleted = 0 AND e.section_id = $1 AND e.grp_id = $2 
ORDER BY parent.data->>'f27' ASC NULLS LAST
```

Comment: I don't see a `data` column in your schema.

Comment: The currently accepted answer is wrong. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Currently it only returns rows where the join matches

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of JOIN to also retrieve the rows that don't "have" a parent.

> I'd like to sort by the "parent"'s name (f27), but if a parent is not linked I'd like to put it at the bottom of the sort.

Instead of

```
ORDER BY parent.data->>'f27' ASC
```

<s>try to fill in the `null`s with a value that would be pushed to the end when sorting (for example, the string `'zzz'`, but think of something that would make sense based on the data you have):</s>

```
ORDER BY coalesce(parent.data->>'f27', 'zzz') ASC
```

use

```
ORDER BY parent.data->>'f27' ASC NULLS LAST
```

(thanks, Marth!)

---

In the end, you query could look like this:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM entry AS e
LEFT JOIN entry as parent 
  ON parent.entry_id = cast(e.data->>'f22' as integer)
WHERE e.deleted = 0 AND e.section_id = $1 AND e.grp_id = $2 
ORDER BY parent.data->>'f27' ASC NULLS LAST
```

Here's a demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d18cc/16

Comment: Any reason not to use `ORDER BY parent.data->>'f27' ASC NULLS LAST` ?

Comment: @Marth Didn't know that option existed. Thanks! I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using `left join` in instead of `inner` all the conditions on the `left join`ed table must be moved from the `where` clause to the `from` clause otherwise you will still be in a `inner join` situation.

```
select e.*
from
    entry as e
    left join
    entry as p on
        p.entry_id = cast(e.data->>'f22' as integer)
        and e.deleted = 0
        and e.section_id = $1
        and e.grp_id = $2 
order by p.data->>'f27' asc nulls last
```

If it is the `parent` table's rows that must be all returned then change `left join` above for `right join`.

Comment: It works the accepted way, but your way is more efficient I guess because there are less attempted joins?

Comment: The accepted answer is just wrong. Check the data and the result set.

Comment: My result set is correct when I used it in my implementation? e is not the left joined table.

Comment: If `e` is not the `left join`ed table how did you accept it is as an answer?  Because there `e` __is__ the `left join`ed table. It looks like you do not get the syntax and I can't understand the problem. Check my updated answer.

Comment: e is the main table. parent gets joined onto it so that I can sort by the parent. Doesn't that mean parent is the left joined table? I'm selecting all entries from e with the exception of rows that don't meet the parameters in my where clause. The "parent"'s section id doesn't have to equal $1. I'll update my question to reflect what I ended up with.